# C# Copy files with pattern and preserve structure

Tags: c#, io, file-copying

I am using a Workflow Foundation code activity to copy a set of files using a wildcard pattern from a folder to another. I must keep the folder structure, so for example, in this case:

```
C:\
  - MyFile.txt
  - MyChildFolder
    - MyFile.txt
```

Should be copied in this way:

```
C:\
  - DestinationFolder
    - MyFile.txt
    - MyChildFolder
      - MyFile.txt
```

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
// copy using the pattern
var filesToCopy = sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
filesToCopy.ToList().ForEach(fileToCopy =>
{

    File.Copy(fileToCopy.FullName, Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryInfo.FullName, fileToCopy.Name), true);
});
```

So what happens here is that I end up with all the files copied in the root destination directory. Unfortunately I get an array of files so I can't use the CopyFolder method at all.

Comment: If you want to keep the folder structure, shouldn't `MyChildFolder` be located inside `DestinationFolder`, due to `MyFile.txt` and `MyChildFolder` in the source are the same level?

Comment: Yes Herdo, I just fixed it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by calling from my code an xcopy command.

I can easily use xcopy in this way:

```
xcopy "source\*.txt" "destination" /e
```

and it will simply copy everything and preserving the folder structure.